# Plugin jce editor joomla not working when pulled

Tags: plugins, joomla

I installed `JCE EDITOR` in `joomla 2.5`. i pushed all file and extension database in my project.
But `JCE EDITOR` not working when another computer pulled it.

Someone help!

it must be like :

[image]

but now not work:
[image]

Or how can push a plugin to git?

Comment: Why you pushed the files, after successful installation all files are pushed directly

Comment: i'm using git to push it.it worked on my PC

Comment: Then what issue are you facing ?

Comment: when i git clone to another computer. JCE editor isn't display toolbar when i edit articles

Answer (score 0):

Might there be some file permission error? If you have ssh-access to your server, you can try this: Navigate to your www root folder (often called www, public_html or something similar), try doing something like:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

in a terminal. This should give all files 644 permissions, and all folders 755 permissions.

If you do not have ssh access then you need to use whatever other server access you have (perhaps cpanel?) and change permission on files to 644 and folders to 755.

Comment: what am i doing with this? I'm newcommer

Comment: i dont think so. JCE editor is in somewhere on my database, not only in table extension in database

Comment: Git can sometimes mess with permissions on files, depending on local settings. If a file is not readable, what you are seeing might be the result.